# Is there any way to get feedback on how effective editing questions is?

Tags: discussion, edits, downvotes

When we ask a question that gets downvoted due to reasons such as:

- poor description
- code that is not working
- etc

We are under the impression that editing our questions according to Stack Overflow rules will improve the quality of our questions and people may reconsider their downvoting decisions.

But in reality, I think it is unlikely for a voter to actively review the questions that he / she downvoted, letting alone reviewing that question quality.

Is there anyway to get feedback on how effective editing questions is or how likely for a voter to revisit a question that has been improved?

Comment: There might be a way to get that information using SE Data query, but wouldn't you be more interested in how new visitors judge the edited question? New visitors can easily outnumber the ones who had already downvoted.

Comment: @Tom, yeah, I agree with you; but overtime, a question will sink to its bottom, with less and less visitors. It may be interesting to plot how many visitors a question gets over time as well.

Comment: To get sensible stats one would need to know if an edit actually improves posts. When a post gets closed, it's not that rare for the author to edit in a rant about it being closed unjustly. I don't think this can be answered without manually appraising edits and looking at the timelines, which would be very labor-intensive.

Comment: @ErikA Not to mention subjective.

Comment: The point is not (really) for those who already voted to change their vote, but it is rather for others to upvote, which would "cancel out" those downvotes.

Comment: It does happen that clarifying edits cause downvotes to be reversed, and it’s probably happening more often than you think. But, still, your instincts are not wrong. You only get one chance to make a first impression. It’s therefore important that the question be complete, self-contained, and as well-presented as possible *when you first post it*. The edit feature is really more of an escape hatch than something you should count on. You do have an infinite amount of time to get it right *before* hitting the submit button, so the initial votes are not altogether unfair.

Comment: I tend to leave a comment now and then when I think a post could be improved by its author. In certain cases I also downvote or VTC. When an OP responds to my comment stating he addressed the issues I raised I am more then happy to retract my CV and DV, and when the question deserves it even upvote.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't have any real data about this, just my own observations and opinions as someone who downvotes questions that might get edited later, but I'll share that for what it's worth.

First, I think it depends on how bad the question was to begin with. If people think a question looks completely hopeless, they are not likely to bother looking at it again after they down/close vote, except possibly to vote to delete it. If you get multiple down/close votes fairly quickly, it's probably a good indication that people *do* think it's that bad, and the votes are very unlikely to be reversed.

Second, I think the chances of people revisiting a question that's *not* that bad is greater than you think it is, and the probability of votes being reversed increases quite a bit if the question author responds to suggestions for improvement. People often complain about downvotes without explanation, but there really are plenty of cases where helpful comments are given along with downvotes, whether they came from the downvoters or not, and I've never understood why it's so rare for someone to try to make the improvements that were suggested, or even acknowledge them.

I often go back through my recent comments and check on questions where I suggested improvements and I doubt I'm the only one who does. If the question was improved, I will remove the downvote or retract the close vote. But if I or others have told the author about some things that they need to add or change to make the question answerable and they've ignored it, I'm much more likely to downvote if I haven't already. Not because I'm upset with the question author for ignoring the advice, just because whatever hope I had of the question being improved is gone.

Comment: Thanks, I learned something from your post. I will try to live up to your example.

Comment: Same here. I often leave questions I’m interested in but have problems open in tabs to check back on them later. I’ll happily adjust my vote and/or re-open if clarifications are made, but it is unfortunately quite rare that that happens. I will never understand why. When it all works, it feels like a small miracle, and really brightens my day.